# Find td with specific title and get one of its attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 tables on my page, `#seats` and `#wings`.
Now I have to check which td inside `table#seats` contains a special title, then check what the value of its attr "`seq`" is, and finally add a class to the corresponding `td` in`table#wings`.

```
<table id="seats">
<tr>
    <td title="" seq="1">Info</td>
    <td title="Exit Row Seat" seq="2">Info</td>
    <td title="" seq="3">Info</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My Code so far:

```
$("table#seats tr td[title*='Exit Row Seat']").each(function () {
     var count = $(this).attr("seq");
     $("table#wings tr td:nth-child(" + count + ")").addClass('exitRow');
});
```

My Problem is, that I get all of the td's back, not only those with the title tag I am looking for. What do I do wrong?

Comment: This should work. Maybe you have more than one table#seats in your DOM.

Comment: You can check with `$('table').length` with the F12 console.

Comment: @JacquesMarais It works if you have the correct elements in the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/4gp908qu/

Comment: @George Oh sorry, I misread the question..

Comment: @George, your sample does not work for me, that's the prob.

Comment: It works perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedosama/eaou4wsk/1/

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi What browser are you using?

Comment: @Mohamed Oasama, I've updated your sample, now one can see the result. This works indeed, THX!!
https://jsfiddle.net/eaou4wsk/3/

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to iterate all `td` and then read the attribute:

```js
$("table#seats tr td").each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('title') == "Exit Row Seat") {
       var count = $(this).attr("seq");
       $(this).addClass('exitRow');
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, makes sense. Just one thing: in you example the full title has to be "Exit Row Seats", but the title will contain even more text, so I need the td that CONTAINS "Exit Row Seat"

Answer (score 0):

My solution at the end:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allSeatTables.length; i++) {
     $("td[title*='Exit']", allSeatTables[i]).each(function () {
        var count = $(this).attr("seq");                                
        $(("td:eq(" + count + ")"), allWingRow[i]).addClass("exitRow");
     });                           
}
```